# Visual Basic program returns "run-time error '-2147024726 (800700aa)"

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation

This is my school project, I need to take the data from Excel sheet to a website and submit. I'm confused about the loop and range.

```
Sub test()
    Dim GC As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim i As Integer

    Set GC = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    GC.Visible = True

    i = 1
    Do
        i = i + 1

        GC.navigate "www.google.com"

        Do While GC.Busy
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop

        Set doc = GC.document
        doc.getElementById("recovery_code_entry").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("W").Range("A1").Value
        doc.getElementById("reset_action").Click
    Loop Until i > 50
End Sub
```

I get this:

> run-time error '-2147024726 (800700aa)

I cannot withdraw the data column from Excel Sheet

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: Can you write these lines after `Set doc = GC.document` and tell us what output you get in the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G): `Debug.Print TypeName(GC.document)` `Debug.Print TypeName(doc.getElementById("recovery_code_entry"))` `Debug.Print TypeName(doc.getElementById("reset_action"))`

Comment: Do you really need to keep navigating back to same url? Does the click take you to a different page?

Comment: I had this error when trying to run code from a work computer. From my research of this error, it means that we don't have permission to do certain things. Have you tried running the code as an administrator?

Comment: As you did not specify on which line you got this error, it is difficult for us to guess the cause for this issue. If you are getting this error on GC.navigate than try to lower down the security settings in IE for testing purpose. If you are getting this error on loop than try to wait for some more time. I suggest you to try to debug your code step by step may help you to find the problematic line which helps to   narrow down the issue.

Comment: When I debug, I got this in yellow line                                           GC.navigate "www.google.com" and  got this message "run-time error '-2147024726 (800700aa)"","method navigate of object iwebbrowser2 failed" Anyone know what happen?

Comment: @ abbsiche I just run as normal.

Comment: Did you try to lower down the security levels of IE to check whether it solves the issue or not? If yes, let us know about your testing results. We will try to provide further suggestions, if needed.